# Transfer next and previous functions from a generic doublelinked list to a specific

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I am making a card game, but having some problems implementing my double linked list and adding cards etc.

I want to store 52 Card(s) from my card class (which is just an object with only the value IndexValue (from 1-52) In a double linked list to represent a deck of cards, and then i want to be able to preform operations like drawing cards from it, which should return the next cards in the deck.

My problem is that in the DoubleLinkedList cards I am storing Cards, but when i want to draw the next card (or previous or w/e) i cannot do like currCard.next since currCard is a Card and not an Element and thus it doesn't have any of the next or previous pointers in the element class. I just cant figure out how co transfer those attributes over. I have been stuck for days now been googling around about generics etc but just cant find it

My doubleLinkedList class:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class DoubleLinkedList<E> {

protected transient Element<E> head;
protected transient Element<E> tail;
protected transient int size;

public DoubleLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public E removeFirst() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    Element<E> temp = head;
    head = head.next;
    head.previous = null;
    size--;
    return temp.indexValue;
}

public void addFirst(E value) {                     
    head = new Element<E>(value, head, null);
    if(tail == null) tail = head;
    size++;
}

public E getFirst() {
    return head.indexValue;                     
}

public void addLast(E value) {                  
    tail = new Element<E>(value, null, tail);
    if(head == null) head = tail;
    size++;
}

public E removeLast() {                         
    if (size == 0){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    Element<E> temp = tail;
    tail = tail.previous;
    tail.next = null;
    size --;
    return temp.indexValue; 
}

public E getLast() {        
    if (size == 0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Element<E> finger = head;
    while(finger.next != null) {
        finger = finger.next;
    }
    return finger.indexValue;
}

public boolean contains(E value) {          
    Element<E> finger = head;

    while(head.next != null && !finger.indexValue.equals(value)) {
        finger = finger.next;
    }
    return finger != null;
}


public E remove(Element<Card> currentCard) {            
    Element<E> finger = head;
    while(finger != null && !finger.indexValue.equals(currentCard))
    {
        finger = finger.next;
    }

    if (finger != null)
    {
        if (finger.previous != null)
        {
            finger.previous.next = finger.next;
        }
        else 
        {
            head = finger.next;
        }
        if (finger.next != null)
        {
            finger.next.previous = finger.previous;
        } 
        else
        {
            tail = finger.previous;
        }
        size --;
        return finger.indexValue;                               
    }
    return null;
}

public E getValueAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if (index == 0) {
        getFirst();
    } else if (index == size -1) {
        return getLast();
    }
    Element<E> finger = head;
    while (index > 0) {
        finger = finger.next;
        index--;
    }
    return finger.indexValue;
}

protected static class Element<E> {

    public E indexValue;
    public Element<E> next;
    public Element<E> previous;

    public Element(E value, Element<E> next, Element<E> previous) {
        this.indexValue = value;
        this.next = next;
        if(next!= null){
            next.previous=this;
        }
        this.previous = previous;

        if(previous!=null){
            previous.next=this;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Carddeck class

```
public class CardDeck<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends DoubleLinkedList<E> {


private static DoubleLinkedList<Card> cards = new DoubleLinkedList<Card>();  //Chose to use doubly linked list instead of circular because in a normal solitaire game you will go to the end of the deck, and then restart, not just go around and around. 
static int currentCard = -1;  // the current card's index in the decklist

static Card newCard;
static List<Integer> newCards = new ArrayList<Integer>(52);

public CardDeck() {

    newCards = new ArrayList<Integer>(52);
    cards = new DoubleLinkedList<Card>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++) {          //creates a list with the numbers from 1 to 52
        newCards.add(i);                    // then shuffles it and creates the full deck in random order
    }

    Collections.shuffle(newCards);

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {          

        newCard = new Card(newCards.get(i));
        System.out.println(newCards.get(i));
        System.out.print(newCard); 
        cards.addLast(newCard);
    }


}

public static void drawCard()   {

    Card currCard = cards.getValueAtIndex(currentCard-1);

    if (currentCard == -1)
    {                                   //if there yet is no current card the current card will begin on the head of the list
        currCard = cards.head.indexValue;
        currentCard = 0;
    }
    else if(cards.currCard.next.indexValue == null)     //Error here on the .next since its a Card and not an Element<Card>
    {
        currCard = cards.head.indexValue;
        currentCard = 0;
    }
    else
    {

        currCard = cards.getValueAtIndex(currentCard).next;

    }


}
```

Comment: I think you can use java.util.LinkedList in this case, as it allows you to go back and forth, add, remove...

Comment: @AleZalazar So if i use from java.util.LinkedList:   LinkedList<Card> cards = new DoubleLinkedList<Card>(); then add an binch of Card in there, How can say find the Next/previous Card of a specific card like static card newCard = new Card(1);   by newCard.next etc?

Comment: Actually you should do LinkedList<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>(); if you want the position of a card, use indexOf(card); with that index you could get a listIterator(index) and navigate in there... remember in Java you need a well defined equals/hashcode method in Card class

Comment: I just found out i have been thinking completely wrong all along... the next/prevous pointers in the elements inside the list is just there for the internal methods like addLast etc, and that i should as you say just use index in the lists itself to find next/previous elements. I feel so annoyed now thinking for days how to solve somehting i didnt have to in the first place xD Thanks